# IE issue - NameCtrl Class warning

Tags: 2013, error, internet-explorer, popup

When loading SharePoint 2013 website in IE 11 I get an IE popup "**This webpage wants to run NameCtrl Class which is not compatible with Internet Explorer's enhanced security features**"

What is NameCtrl? Can it be disabled in SharePoint (not in IE)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NameCtrl is the activex control that is used to determine the user's presence.  It is reflected in the web UI by showing red/green icons next to the user's name in a view for example to indicate if a user is online or not.  It also enables the ability to perform certain actions in the UI.

This may help:
http://sympmarc.com/tag/namectrl-class/

But yes, individual users can disable it in IE if they/you don't intend to or want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

There was replaced right path to NAME.DLL file in your office ...
For us was replaced to OFFICE15, but we still using path to OFFICE14 folder, where is the NAME.DLL, some of us computers where changed to folder "root\OFFICE16" with file "`interceptor.dll`" 
Just repair it in registry solved our problems

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID{E18FEC31-2EA1-49A2-A7A6-902DC0D1FF05}\InprocServer32]
>   @="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\NAME.DLL"
>   "InprocServer32"=hex(7):79,00,68,00,31,00,42,00,56,00,3f,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,\
>   21,00,34,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,4d,00,4b,00,4b,00,53,00,6b,00,49,00,4d,\
>   00,4e,00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,3e,00,5a,00,7d,00,21,00,36,00,25,00,\
>   63,00,65,00,5d,00,7e,00,3f,00,3d,00,32,00,4d,00,62,00,64,00,4b,00,57,00,6a,\
>   00,27,00,6b,00,00,00,79,00,68,00,31,00,42,00,56,00,7a,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,\
>   21,00,34,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,4d,00,4b,00,4b,00,53,00,6b,00,49,00,4d,\
>   00,4e,00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,3e,00,5a,00,7d,00,21,00,36,00,25,00,\
>   63,00,65,00,5d,00,7e,00,3f,00,3d,00,32,00,4d,00,62,00,64,00,4b,00,57,00,6a,\
>   00,27,00,6b,00,00,00,79,00,68,00,31,00,42,00,56,00,35,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,\
>   21,00,34,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,4d,00,4b,00,4b,00,53,00,6b,00,49,00,4d,\
>   00,4e,00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,3e,00,5a,00,7d,00,21,00,36,00,25,00,\
>   63,00,65,00,5d,00,7e,00,3f,00,3d,00,32,00,4d,00,62,00,64,00,4b,00,57,00,6a,\
>   00,27,00,6b,00,00,00,00,00 "ThreadingModel"="Apartment"
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID{E18FEC31-2EA1-49A2-A7A6-902DC0D1FF05}\InprocServer32]
>   @="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\NAME.DLL"
>   "InprocServer32"=hex(7):79,00,68,00,31,00,42,00,56,00,3f,00,25,00,21,00,21,00,\
>   21,00,34,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,4d,00,4b,00,4b,00,53,00,6b,00,49,00,4d,\
>   00,4e,00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,33,00,32,00,3e,00,3d,00,4d,00,77,00,\
>   53,00,71,00,47,00,4f,00,55,00,78,00,3f,00,24,00,64,00,42,00,32,00,33,00,29,\
>   00,51,00,49,00,59,00,79,00,00,00,00,00 "ThreadingModel"="Apartment"
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID{E18FEC31-2EA1-49A2-A7A6-902DC0D1FF05}\InprocServer32]
>   @="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\NAME.DLL"
>   "InprocServer32"=hex(7):79,00,68,00,31,00,42,00,56,00,3f,00,25,00,21,00,21,00,\
>   21,00,34,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,4d,00,4b,00,4b,00,53,00,6b,00,49,00,4d,\
>   00,4e,00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,33,00,32,00,3e,00,3d,00,4d,00,77,00,\
>   53,00,71,00,47,00,4f,00,55,00,78,00,3f,00,24,00,64,00,42,00,32,00,33,00,29,\
>   00,51,00,49,00,59,00,79,00,00,00,00,00 "ThreadingModel"="Apartment"